# Send and recieve a file over a socket in C

Tags: c, windows, file, sockets

I've noticed there's a built-in function for C++ and C# and so, but C doesn't. (I'm on a windows machine).

So I wrote these two functions but they are not working, they just get stuck (I suspect it's the sending one because when the client's recieving he just gets an error according to the function return value).

Here are the functions (the sockets between the server and the client are working properly, I've tested it):

```
int recvFile(SOCKET s, const char* file_path)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(file_path, "wb");
    char* file_buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*PACKAGE_LEN); //so it will be 0
    int bytesRecieved, bytesWritten;
    if(!fp)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        free(file_buf);
        return 1;
    }

    do
    {
        bytesRecieved = recv(s, file_buf, PACKAGE_LEN, 0); //receiving that file buffer in the size of PACKAGE_LEN (maximum chunk size). 
        if(bytesRecieved != PACKAGE_LEN)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            free(file_buf);
            return 1; //if there's an error...
        }
        if(!charPresent(file_buf, PACKAGE_LEN, EOF)) //as long as there's no EOF character in the file buffer received now.
        {
            fwrite(file_buf, sizeof(char), PACKAGE_LEN, fp); //write to file normally.
        }
    }
    while(!charPresent(file_buf, PACKAGE_LEN, EOF)); // do it as long there's no EOF in the file buffer.
    fwrite(file_buf, sizeof(char), indexOf(file_buf, PACKAGE_LEN, EOF), fp); //the last time you write the file buffer including the EOF is outside the loop.

    fclose(fp);
    free(file_buf);

    return 0;
}

int charPresent(const char* str, size_t size, char ch)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == ch)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int indexOf(const char* str, size_t size, char ch)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == ch)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

(not much place to make a mistake when it comes to the function `charPresent()` and `IndexOf`though - I'm not using `strlen()` on purpose because `\0` is not promised to be in that buffer). and...:

```
int sendFile(SOCKET s, const char* file_path)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    int i, err = 0, bytesSent, isOk = 1;
    char* file_buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*PACKAGE_LEN);
    char ch = 0;
    if(!fp)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        free(file_buf);
        return 1;
    }
    while(ch != EOF && isOk)
    {
        i = 0;
        do
        {
            do
            {
                err = ((fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, fp)) != 1);
                file_buf[i] = ch;
            }
            while(err); //keep reading until read successfully.
            i++;
            if(i == PACKAGE_LEN) //means we achieved the maximum chunk size.
            {
                isOk = 0; //to exit the inner loop.
            }
        }
        while(ch != EOF && isOk);
        bytesSent = send(s, file_buf, PACKAGE_LEN, 0); //sending the file buffer over the socket.
        if(bytesSent != PACKAGE_LEN)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            free(file_buf);
            return 1; //return an error (it is taken care of later on).
        }
        isOk = 1; // so the loop won't stop because we achieved only one chunk.
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(file_buf);

    return 0;
}
```

What have I done wrong? :P
I thought of an alternate which is just to find out the length of the file and loop `FILE_LEN/PACKAGE_LEN + ((!(FILE_LEN%PACKAGE_LEN))?(0):(1))` and in the last run just send the one with the EOF but basically it's the same concept, I think.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @JohnZwinck windows, forgot to mention that :P

Comment: (OT) For both your `indexOf` and `charPresent` you could use `memchr`.

Comment: @Jongware I know, I wrote my own functions just so I'll have a better control over the program's flow.

Comment: No offense, but this code is so wrong it's probably not salvageable. Did you make a specification for the protocol you're using? Because it looks like there are a lot of things not addressed. (For example, if the file size is not a multiple of the buffer size. If the receiver gets a partial buffer. Your use of `EOF` reflects a fundamental misunderstanding of how files end. And so on.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why wrong ? It's TCP and the buffer can be partial, lol, didn't you look after the loop ? It won't stop untill EOF is present in the buffer passed.

Comment: The buffer can't be partial. If your `recv` gets less than `PACKAGE_LEN`, you barf.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why that language? My recv NEVER gets less than PACKAGE_LEN, it's always PACKAGE_LEN, my fwrite() though, sometimes gets less.

Comment: @Zach **If** your `recv` gets less than `PACKAGE_LEN`, you barf. There's no way you can ensure it doesn't (unless `PACKAGE_LEN` is 1). So your code is badly broken. TCP can't "glue" characters together into messages, it's not a message protocol.

Comment: @DavidSchwarts, I didn't understand - my recv NEVER gets less than PACKAGE_LEN, it's in the protocol my program works on. So where's the problem ?

Comment: @Zach Do you understand what these words mean: "TCP is a byte-stream protocol that does not preserve application message boundaries". If not, please google that phrase until you understand it. You are expecting TCP to preserve application message boundaries, and your code barfs if it doesn't. TCP just doesn't do that. You can't "glue" bytes into messages. TCP is *not* a message protocol. See [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code's really not salvageable. You should honestly start over.

Before you write any code, have a look at some protocol specifications for other protocols that use TCP. You can look at FTP, HTTP, SMTP, and so on.

Pay particular attention to how they delimit messages. And keep in mind that TCP is a byte-stream protocol -- it does not preserve message boundaries.

I strongly advise you to go to the trouble of writing a specification. That way, if your code doesn't work, you can figure out which side is not complying with the specification. (If they both are, and it still doesn't work, the specification is broken.) Otherwise, there's no way to figure out what's wrong, because there's no statement of what's right.

Also, you can't use `EOF` that way. There is no character that represents end of file. Every possible character value can be contained in a file. There's no "extra" character that can mean "end of file".

Comment: So do you recommend on going for UDP ? My protocol assures arrival of message anyway, by itself.

Comment: UDP is much more complex to use than TCP. All the things TCP does for you, you have to do yourself with UDP if you need them. That includes: connection setup and teardown, out of order detection and reordering, exponential backoff, transmit pacing, retransmissions, and so on.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean. I want you to succeed. Maybe instead of trying to write raw socket code, you should use a library that provides a higher-level interface, including messaging, error handling, and so on. (You can't really learn by trial and error because a lot of really bad things will "happen to work" under some conditions. There's a cost of admission to get networking right, and it's not easy.)

Comment: If I send a byte-by-byte and recieve a byte-by-byte, will it be better ? I'm not talking about speed, I'm talking about how it could get wrong. Because as long as I know - TCP is preventing disorder in the data, I will just stream bytes untill I see a value that says "the file stops here", maybe just a random number like -32 or anything that 'char' can contain and is negative.

Comment: If you receive byte by byte, you avoid short receives. If you send byte by byte, you avoid having to figure out what to put in the buffer if the file size isn't a perfect multiple of the buffer size. But you still have to figure out a sane way for the receiver to identify the end of the file. Every value a character can hold is a value that can appear in a file. There is no "extra value" to indicate end of file. If you want to be silly, send a one before each data byte in the file and a zero at the end. Then the receiver will know that one means to receive a data byte and zero means to stop.

Comment: But I hope my answer shows my main point -- You have to *design* and *specify* a protocol that ensures both sides work together. Please don't start with code. You can't possibly get it right because you don't even know what it's supposed to do.